# How do we call items taking part in undirect relation?

Tags: single-word-requests

When I have **a directed relation** I call one of the items taking part **a subject** and other **an object**. Is there a corresponding term for **a bidirectional relation**? I know I can call both items a relation **objects**, but I would like some other term to distinguish from directed relation.

Comment: What is a "directed relation"?

Comment: When you have a relation *hasChild*, it is **directed** and subject is a parent and object is a child. Example of an **undirected** relation would be for example *knows*, because when you know somebody he/she also knows you.

Comment: _Knows_ sounds rather _bidirectional_ then, I think.

Comment: I *copied* this from directed and undirected graphs. But I agree bidrectional is more understandable. I corrected the question.

Comment: I'd tend to put on my programming hat and say "unidirectional" and "bidirectional".  Though one might also use "association" to refer to a linkage whose direction is not defined.

Comment: Hmm.  This sounds more like a function than a relation.

Comment: @aparente001 A function that maps two objects to {0,1} is a relation.

Answer (score 2):

[participants](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/participant//) [Source: ODO]

Examples of usage:

- > '*a situation with two participants between which a bidirectional relation holds*'

Source: [Reciprocity in English: historical development and synchronic structure. *Haas, F* Routledge, 2010](https://books.google.co.uk/books?id=QiCNAgAAQBAJ&pg=PA48&lpg=PA48&dq=bidirectional%20relation%20particip*&source=bl&ots=hJpMp9yjzB&sig=MhcCt4T_Cy2ebB0pCawDoJs5iRo&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0CC8Q6AEwAmoVChMI3-7H99OyxwIVS1caCh02WwdZ#v=onepage&q=bidirectional%20relation%20particip*&f=false)

- > '*It is a bidirectional relation denoting that two participants are socially connected and it corresponds to the generic relation offered by existing social networks.*'

Source: [Enterprise, business-process and information systems modeling. [LNBIP 175] Springer, 2014](https://books.google.co.uk/books?id=6c25BQAAQBAJ&pg=PA98&lpg=PA98&dq=bidirectional%20relation%20participants&source=bl&ots=WM5Nnaj57w&sig=HBd8aKhuzrkoju8eo6DqVAkn4Oo&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0CDQQ6AEwA2oVChMIvez8mdeyxwIVRToaCh2ULgxb#v=onepage&q=bidirectional%20relation%20participants&f=false)

Answer (score 1):

Reflexives appear to be one form of bidirectional object:

***Reflexive***:
"He injured himself."
"[He perjured himself.](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/perjure#Verb)" (ref. Wiktionary)

And Reciprocal ([Merriam Webster](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/reciprocal)) describes another *situation*:

> —used to describe a relationship in which two people or groups agree
>   to do something similar for each other, to allow each other to have
>   the same rights, etc.

hence: ***Reciprocal Pronouns:***  ([englishclub.com](https://www.englishclub.com/grammar/pronouns-reciprocal.htm))

"each other,"  "one another"